# Is it possible to use data frame in r-exams?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I would like to paste the data-frame from the R environment to the latex part (question or solution part) when creating exercises in r-exams. Later the exercises will be imported into Moodle. Is that possible in r-exams? We saw it is possible when the object is matrix object via `$\Sexpr{toLatex(matrix_obj)}$`. But a similar way does not seem to work with the data-frames. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.frame` would usually be included as a `{tabular}` in LaTeX and there are various packages for automatic conversion like `xtable` or using the function `kable()` in `knitr`. For PDF output this also works nicely including all vertical and/or horizontal lines included in the table. However, for HTML-based output (as for Moodle) the table as such is converted correctly but without any lines.

An overview of a couple of solutions is available as:

[Different copies of question with table for Moodle with R-Exams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222053/different-copies-of-question-with-table-for-moodle-with-r-exams)

Moreover, Kenji Sato has proposed to inject some dedicated CSS code to handle the table formatting in HTML. We are currently working on some automated way of including this in R/exams:

https://www.kenjisato.jp/en/post/2020/07/moodle-bordered-table/